# Order of evaluation in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I have the following function of three variables:

```
sbbf[ω_,κ2_,g2_]:=(38.4` g2^2 Sqrt[κ2^2])/(16 g2^4 (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 + 
   8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 
      4 ω^2)) + 
8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) + 
   4 (κ2/10000 + 4 ω^2))) + (9.6` (κ2^2 + 
  4 ω^2))/(16 g2^4 (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 + 
   8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 
      4 ω^2)) + 
8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) + 
   4 (κ2/10000 + 4 ω^2))) + (0.0122` (16 g2^4 + 
  8 g2^2 (κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (1 + 
     4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2)))/(16 g2^4 (1/
   100000000 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 + 
   8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 
      4 ω^2)) + 
8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) + 
   4 (κ2/10000 + 4 ω^2)))
```

I wish to integrate sbbf with respect to ω. I do the following:

```
T = 
Table[{cc2, 
NIntegrate[
Evaluate[(sbbf /. {g2 -> 
      Sqrt[ cc2]/2*Sqrt[κ1*κ2]}) /. { κ2 -> 
    10.}], {ω, -100, 100}]}, {cc2, 0, 100, 0.1}]
```

And I run into an error that says: *the integrand sbbf has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,100}}*. I proceed to look about this online and found something that seemed relevant from this article: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502

From what I can understand, it appears that the function is undefined for non-numeric values (perhaps κ2 and cc2?) and NIntegrate is unable to evaluate it. I think the solution is to reverse the order of evaluation (integrate only when the input constants are numeric). So I proceeded to do the following modification:

```
T[cc2_?NumericQ] := 
Table[{cc2, 
NIntegrate[
Evaluate[(sbbf /. {g2 -> 
      Sqrt[ cc2]/2*Sqrt[κ1*κ2]}) /. { κ2 -> 
    10.}], {ω, -100, 100}]}, {cc2, 0, 100, 0.1}]
```

Unfortunately the above fix did not work and I suspected that I need more ?NumericQ for my other constants. So I did

```
T[cc2_?NumericQ, κ1_?NumericQ, κ2_?NumericQ, g2_?NumericQ]:= ...
```

For good measure but unfortunately that didn't work as well. I am quite lost at this moment and I could use any help that I can get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you tried was sensible but there remains a symbolic κ1 in the input.

Comment: What is the value of `κ1` supposed to be?

Comment: Apologies, \[Kappa]1 goes to 1. I placed that right before \[Kappa]2 -> 10 but it still didn't work.

Comment: `sbbf` by itself (without [args]) has not been defined. you should use `sbbf[Sqrt[ cc2]/2*Sqrt[κ1*κ2],10.,w]`

Comment: @george2079 I think what you meant was to put the first argument as w, followed by 10 for k2 and 'Sqrt[cc2*k1*k2]/2' (your order of argument is different from mine). But it worked without the need for defining ?NumericQ for my table T.

Comment: right. Note also your `T[cc2_?NumericQ] := ` will not work anyway because `cc2` is the table iterator and it makes no sense to give it a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, as you already have defined `sbbf`:

```
pts={#, NIntegrate[sbbf[\[Omega], 10, Sqrt[#]/2*Sqrt[10]], {\[Omega], -100, 100}]} 
 & /@ Range[0, 100, .1]
ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True,AxesLabel -> {"cc2", "Integral"}]
```

[image]

and by seeing the result, no need to use fine sampling in `cc2`.