# Unable to solve for roots (trivial)

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following function:

```
f[ω_] := (2 Sqrt[Γ] (4 g2^2 + (κ1 - 
   2 Iω) (κ2 - 2 Iω)))/(
4 g2^2 (Γ - 
 2 Iω) + (4 g1^2 + (Γ - 
    2 Iω) (κ1 - 2 Iω)) (κ2 - 
 2 Iω))
```

And I wish to solve for the roots of its denominator. I do the following:

```
wroots1 = Solve[Denominator[f] == 0, ω] // FullSimplify
```

However, that spits out just

```
{}
```

I suspect it's the naming of the variable ω, so I redefined the variable like so:

```
wroots1 = x /. Solve[(Denominator[f] /. {ω -> x}) == 0, x]//FullSimplify
```

and I get only

```
x
```

I know this might be a trivial issue but I've spent an hour on this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `Iω` is different from `I ω`; mind your spaces when multiplying variables!

Comment: I've fixed it as 'I*\[Omega]' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: you made the exact same mistake here as in this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167673/2079.  You define a function `f[w_] := ..`.  In order to use such function as you are trying to do you need to supply arguments when you evaluate.  `Denominator[f[w]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Iw` is a variable name; `I w` is `Sqrt[-1] w`. Therefore,

```
f[ω_] := 
  (2 Sqrt[Γ] (4 g2^2 + (κ1 - 2 I ω) (κ2 - 2 I ω))) / 
    (4 g2^2 (Γ - 2 I ω) + (4 g1^2 + (Γ - 2 I ω) (κ1 - 2 I ω)) (κ2 - 2 I ω))
Solve[Denominator[f[ω]] == 0, ω] // Short
```

This gives a big result:

[image: result]